# How can I login when springsecurity.debg.useFilter = false

Tags: spring-security, grails-plugin, grails3

Grails: 3.1.6
Spring security core: 3.1.1
Java: 1.8

I have a custom login form, and a custom login controller.
The login form points to the login controller's index method which then forwards to the filterProcessUrl: 
`forward uri: "${request.contextPath}${getConf().apf.filterProcessesUrl}", params: params`

I'm able to login when I set `grails.plugin.springsecurity.debug.useFilter = true`

When I set `grails.plugin.springsecurity.debug.useFilter = false` in my application.groovy, I'm sent to my 404 page when I try to log in.  It's like the `apf.filterProcessesUrl`, '/login/authenticate', is no longer recognized as a valid URL. I can see in the logs that it never runs any of the filters on the filterProcessesUrl but jumps directly from 'login/index' to '/error' and doesn't trigger 'AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent'.

Why does it only work when I have the debug.useFilter = true?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out forwarding to the filterProcessUrl was the problem. When I stopped forwarding I was able to login. The filter chain was looking at the `request.requestURI` which forwarding didn't change.

The forwarded request was working when I was using the debug filter because the debug filter wraps the original request, which I guess changed the `request.requestURI` and would then get picked up by the filter chain.